# join com duas tabelas e um campo varchar2

Tags: oracle

Olá. Estou usando o oracle 11 g.

Estou tentando fazer uma busca numa tabela de estado por uma determinada cidade.

Por exemplo, o estado Bahia tem várias cidade. Se for informado Salvador, deverá retornar o estado Bahia. A query que estou tentando fazer é:

```
select * from estado as e join cidade as c on e.id_estado=c.fk_id_cidade on c.cidade='Salvador';
```

Dá o erro que o comando foi   encerrado inadequadamente.

Se eu fizer:

```
select * from estado as e join cidade as c on e.id_estado=c.fk_id_cidade;
```

Funciona, mas trás várias cidades. Se eu passasse o id duma cidade, encontraria, mas o parâmetro de busca é pelo nome da cidade.

Comment: @Bacco também não funciona. Tentei usar group by estado, mas tamb´me não funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Para filtrar um resultado por uma condição fora do `JOIN` se usa `WHERE`.

Aproveitando, pode simplificar assim:

```
SELECT * FROM cidade AS c, estado AS e
  WHERE e.id_estado=c.fk_id_cidade AND c.cidade='Salvador';
```

Se for filtrar depois de um agrupamento, se usa `HAVING` no lugar do `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz assim:

```
select*from estado as e join cidade as c on e.id_estado=c.fk_id_cidade and c.cidade='Salvador';
```

Uma variável pode ser passada como parâmetro para o atributo cidade.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM ESTADO E INNER JOIN CIDADE C
ON (E.id_estado = C.fk_id_cidade)
WHERE C.cidade LIKE @pNomeCidade ;
```